# how to create index mongodb properly?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-indexes

let say i have this huge documents.

2 of them got this array of object;

```
{
  status: "A",
  group: "public",
  "created.dt": ....
}

{
  status: "A",
  group: "private",
  "created.dt": ....
}
```

i indexed and ensure like this :

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({"created.dt":-1});

db.collection.ensureIndex({"created.dt":-1, "status":1});
db.collection.ensureIndex({"created.dt":-1, "group":1});

db.collection.ensureIndex({"created.dt":-1, "status":1, "group":1});
```

Query:

```
db.collection.find(
{
  "status": { 
    $in: ["A", "I"] 
  },
  "asset_group": "public"
},
{
  sort: {
   'created.dt':1
  }
}
).count();
```

is it wrong ?

after i make this index still slow.
please help me proper index.thank you

Comment: One cannot tell without seeing your query (eg: find, sort etc)

Comment: @FirdausRamlan alright, i have edited that post.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

for the following query:

```
db.collection.find(
{
  "status": { 
    $in: ["A", "I"] 
  },
  "asset_group": "public"
},
{
  sort: {
   'created.dt':1
  }
}
).count();
```

The best index will be this:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({"status":1, "asset_group":1, "created.dt":1});
```

or

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({"asset_group":1, "status":1, "created.dt":-1});
```

Since you are querying on

`status`, `asset_group`   - these values can be switched in the index prefix

and sort on `created.dt` field -  therefore `created.at` shuold be the last value in the index prefix.  Note: On sort the index can traverse the reverse order.

For other queries, other indexes might be more suitable.
Read more about [compound indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-compound/).